# Python doesn't understand my string variable

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am trying to make a bot for Telegram using pyTelegramBotAPI, it is a store to download Windows Applications, because of the 50MB limit of sending the telegram. I send the file as a user and get the File_ID, which causes the bot to send 2GB files. Each program has a file.txt with your File_ID written.
The bot reads vlc.txt, sets it as a variable and sends the file.
But the program has an error.

"2020-12-19 21:06:09,106 (**init**.py:489 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: wrong remote file identifier specified: Wrong character in the string""

When I manually put the File_ID in the code, it works perfectly, it can't get the file_id from the variable, and I sent the program to print to make sure the variable contains the File_ID written correctly. What could be causing this?

```
def selecionou(query):
    #pretreatment definition
    download = query.data.count('down')
    info = query.data.count('info')
    prints = query.data.count('prints')
    #app name treatment
    if download > 0:
        name = query.data.replace("down.","")
        print(name)
        file_id = open(f'/home/flaipy/PycharmProjects/Lucas/apps/{name}.txt','r')
        file_id = file_id.read()
        print(file_id)
    #order type treatment
    if download > 0:
        print(file_id)
        bot.send_document(query.message.chat.id, file_id)
```

Comment: Are you positive that the ID you're hardcoding is the exact same as what's in the file?  Is there maybe whitespace or a linebreak in the file?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, because when I went to test it manually by placing the File_ID directly in the code, it identified and sent the file perfectly.

Comment: There might be an extra newline in the file that you're not noticing?   By the way, you really shouldn't be giving both the open file and its contents the same variable name, but that's another matter.

Comment: Yes, I checked and it is only one line in the .txt file, would you like me to send you complete code to test? I can upload it for you.

Comment: You could add `print(repr(file_id))` and compare both results.

Answer (score 0):

I was reading w3schools from the "read ()" method in python, and saw that there is an argument to limit the number of characters, I put 70 and it worked, even in the txt file having no space. It is a tip for those who go through the same problem.

`file_id = file_id.read(70)`